# Npm link try to find module in src folder instead of dist folder

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've worked with Angular CLI Builder by creating a custom builder which extend asset config in `angular.json` in case library has it's own asset. I used `nrwl` for managing workspace.

I create a angular cli builder library and run `npm link`. It creates a dist folder. In the project that uses the library, I run `npm link packagename` but when I run `npm run build`, it says `Can not find module X in path ../src/command`. I don't understand why it looks at `src` folder instead of `dist` folder?

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "packagename",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "builders": "builders.json",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.3",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

And tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["example/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: maybe the problem is in your `package.json` file?

Comment: in `tsconfig` try to change `"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc"`

Comment: I tested but it doesn't work

Comment: Try with just "./dist"

Comment: Thank @DaniyalLukmanov, I post my answer to this question. it's my mistake. Thank so much for spending your time. Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected. When I have a package, I need to point angular.json to use my builder. The problem is when it looks at builders.json

```
{
  "builders": {
    "browser": {
      "implementation": "./dist/browser", --it was "./src/browser"
      "schema": "../../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/schema.json",
      "description": "Add assets and runs @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"
    }
  }
}
```

That's why it points to `src` folder instead of `dist` folder.

Comment: I knew that there was `src` instead of `dist` somewhere )) Glad you could find it by yourself.